# How to pass parameter to storage Uri?

Tags: azure, c#-4.0

I am working on azure could you please help me how to pass parameter to storageUri in azure.

Here they having 5 parameters credientials,blob,queue,table,file
    how to pass parameter  storageuri? please check below code.

```
enter code here  
      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
        string AccountName = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AccountName");
        string AccountKey = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AccountKey");
        StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(AccountName, AccountKey);
        storageAccount = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount(credentials,
                                                              new StorageUri(),
                                                              new StorageUri("https://{0}.queue.core.windows.net"),
                                                              new StorageUri("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net"),
                                                               new StorageUri("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net"));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to pass these storage URI parameters? From your question, it seems you are connecting to standard storage endpoints.

Comment: yes  when we are passing "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https we facing some issue so we are passing the accntnt name and key from  StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey  or StorageCredentials so for that its need end point can you help me how to pass storageuri parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
        var credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
         CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials,
             new StorageUri(new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net", accountName))),
             new StorageUri(new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.queue.core.windows.net", accountName))),
             new StorageUri(new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net", accountName))),
             new StorageUri(new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.file.core.windows.net", accountName)))
             );
```